# Slack entry in dock has no notification badges

Tags: plank

The Slack app serves desktop notifications, but the Plank icon has no notification badges. Is there a way to fix it client-side?

I'm running elementary OS 5.1 Hera.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I installed Slack via the AppCenter.

I've also tried Slack installed via snap and the .deb package using Eddy. I get the same results with each approach.